# Azure Online SQL Database Management is Unavailable

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I am trying to host a sql server on azure to communicate with a node app. I have gone through the process of creating the database server and the database itself successfully. Now, I would like to edit my database structure. From what I have found [online](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn771027.aspx), there should be a way to access the database through the management portal with Azure. Every tutorial and other piece of advice I have found (including the MSDN page linked), has instructed me to find the online db management software by clicking a "manage" button on the page that displays my db.  However, when I navigate to the proper page, there is no "manage" to click. I have tried accessing it in Safari, Chrome, and IE on a Windows 7 VM but nothing has worked. My exact question is: with all things considered, how do I design my database from the azure portal?

Image as proof:

[image]

I'd really appreciate any help with this,

-Alex

Comment: I think this is not available in V12 databases, which is a shame and keeping me from upgrading to V12 at the moment.

Comment: If that is the case, how do I provision a "non V12" db? Or should I just google?

Comment: I don't think you can now.

Comment: Darn. I feel like it must still be possible though. How could they remove functionality with an upgrade?

Comment: I think they expect you to use Visual Studio to manage the database now, which is not very convenient compared to a web version.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Did you create a V12 Database?

The manage button that links you to the Azure SQL Database Management Portal (http://yourservername.database.windows.net) is not supported by a V12 Azure SQL Databases.
 For more info, take a look at the Limitations section of this article:
http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-preview-plan-prepare-upgrade/

---

Microsoft recommends Visual Studio 2013 Community Edition ( A Full Featured IDE - FREE! ). 
 Download link here: https://www.visualstudio.com/products/visual-studio-community-vs

you can run this inside your windows 7 VM

In visual studio 2013, you'll have about the same capabilities as the old Azure SQL Database Management Portal.

Comment: Is this a joke? I have to use a Windows client PC to manage a cloud based SQL database? What about people that don't run Windows? Or people who only work in the cloud? I am sorry about my direct comment but I really have to point out that this appears extremely backwards for a cloud based product.