# I can't manage a server in SQL Azure

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I have two servers in my SQL azure Portal. One of them allow me "manage", so I can login and manage my database. However, in the other one the button "manage" don't display.  In this server just two options are displayed.

What can I do?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Azure Online SQL Database Management is Unavailable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29837141/azure-online-sql-database-management-is-unavailable)

Answer (score 1):

I hypothesize that one server is of version v11 and the other is v12.

Clicking the ‘Manage’ button in Azure Management portal launches the SQL Azure Management (SilverLight) Portal in a new tab in the browser. At this time, we do not plan to support this SilverLight-based SQL Azure Management Portal with V12 databases and servers.

We are working hard on an HTML-based T-SQL editor experience that will deeply integrate with the preview Azure Management Portal. Until then, we encourage customers to use [Visual Studio Community 2013](http://www.visualstudio.com/products/visual-studio-community-vs) which is a full-featured free version of Visual Studio 2013 to connect to Azure SQL databases for tasks such as running T-SQL, designing schema and for offline and online database development.

You can click the the ‘Open in Visual Studio’ in the database page in the Azure Management portal to launch VS2013 on your computer and easily connect to your SQL Database.

In addition, you can also use SQL Server Management Studio 2014 with CU6 to connect to Azure SQL Database. More details are on this [blog post](http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/12/22/client-tooling-updates-for-azure-sql-database).