# Can I still manage my SQL Server through the browser window in the New Azure Portal

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

In the older management portal I was able to do SQL Server database management tasks but in the new portal (green and blue) that functionality seems to be removed. In fact the older Azure portal does not seem to have that functionality more as the always dumps me to the add Silverlight screen (I have added 3 times).

I have a simple datafix but I can not get to the server from my current location.

Comment: Possible duplicate: SQL Database V12 not supported in SQL Azure Management  http://stackoverflow.com/a/30684129/793891

Comment: That is the answer.   It is a shame they did not post something about it when you try to access it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This functionality has be deprecated and removed.

> (http://yourservername.database.windows.net) 
>   Azure SQL Database Management portal:
>
> Cannot manage V12 servers.

ref: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-v12-plan-prepare-upgrade/

Answer (score 1):

If your client is not on Windows see suggestion #01 below.

If you are on Windows probably a good route to managing your Azure database is to download the free SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) from [ https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/mt238290.aspx ] . You wind up wired into your cloud based SQL Server same as you would with an on-premise.

CAVEAT - due to the hardening of Azure SQL Database on firewall rules, you may find yourself going to the Azure Portal a great deal to open the firewall between your local client and your Azure SQL Database.

SUGGESTION #01 - Create a 'dev vm' in Azure and install the SSMS into it.  Azure <-> Azure connections do not get firewall dinged every time the client IP changes.  Shut down the 'dev vm' when you aren't using the tools and save some $s.  Great option for folks who don't use a Windows desktop as well.

SUGGESTION #02 - still want to run SSMS local and hate the firewall restriction.  Open it from 0.0.0.0 to 255.255.255.255 .  I've done this on occasion but only temporarily, and removed the rule very quickly after I was done.

Hope this helps.  Healy in Tampa